# DRF's token authentication with Angular

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I'm using `django` for backend and `Angular` for frontend and DRF for making api calls. I'm making a user login system but currently the user gets logged out on refreshing the page.

For preventing this i'm using `rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token` for generating token's for each user and I'm returning this token in my api call but I've no idea how to use this token in `Angular` to keep the user logged in on refreshing the page?

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from .serializers import LoginSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])
def loginUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        user_serializer = LoginSerializer(data=user_data)
        data = {}
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user = user_serializer.validated_data['user']
            try:
                uid = User.objects.get(
                    username=user['username'])
                if not uid.check_password(user['password']):
                    raise Exception
                token = Token.objects.get(user=uid)
                data['token'] = token.key
                data['response'] = 'Successful login'
                return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            except:
                data['response'] = "Username or password does not exist"
                return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

**user.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '../models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  private login_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/';
  private signup_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/';
  private login_status: boolean = false;
  public login(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.login_url, JSON.stringify(user), {observe: 'response'});
  }
  public signup(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.signup_url, JSON.stringify(user), {observe: 'response'});
  }
  public set_login_status(status: boolean) {
    this.login_status = status;
  }
  public is_logged_in():boolean {
    return this.login_status;
  }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

I'm generating the token while registering the user but I'm not sure how to use it to keep the user authenticated on refreshing?

**P.S.** - I couldn't find any tutorial's regarding this so any tutorial links will also work.